# Using Just Bootstrap 4 Modal Plguin

Tags: modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to use bootstrap 4 modal plugin only. 
I linked the `JQuery` first & then the `JS` file of plugin found in `bootstrap/js/dist/modal.js` in their [Github repo](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/dist/modal.js).

After including *modal.js* it gives me this error in console on page refresh & i am unable to use bootstrap modal.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined

Here's my modal HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Including JQuery & Modal.js above the `</body>` tag

```
<script src="js/vendors/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script src="js/vendors/modal.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You might need to add a reference to `JQuery` first

Comment: I've loaded JQuery first then i am trying to load modal.js file which you can see here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/bootstrap/master/js/dist/modal.js

Comment: Can you edit your question and put a code snippet to reproduce the problem? Just having the script file you want to include isn't enough.

Comment: @JonathanLarouche I've edited my question

Comment: Thank you for editing your post, please also include the Html part that have the <script > blocks that include jquery & the modal.js. And also, can you specify when are you getting the error: When the page load or when you click a button?

Comment: @JonathanLarouche Done! i am getting error on page refresh

Comment: What file does the error say it's coming from?

Comment: at modal.js:9 , at modal.js:10 &  at modal.js:754

Comment: Have you tried including *all* of bootstrap (js + css)?  Pretty sure you can't just take one module and expect it to work without the rest of the framework that it relies on.